# Today Extension iOS

Tags: ios, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I am developing today extension.I am displaying tableview cell within my extension.It is working very well.
But the problem is that, i have also given swipe to delete functionalaity in UITableViewcell, but this is not working.
does swipe feature does not work in Today Extension?

Comment: You should not use horizontal swipe in today extensions, it's reserved for navigation (there is some documentation available about this fact, if I knew out of my head where to find it, this would have been an answer instead of a comment ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do this. From [human interface guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppExtensions.html) for today widgets:

> Avoid enabling horizontal swiping or dragging, because it interferes
>   with navigation between Notification Center areas.